# How can I use sinon to spy on a function that is imported into an ember-cli app?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, sinon

I have an `ember` app built using `ember-cli` conventions and I would like to spy on a `util` function using `sinon`. The problem is I don't know how to reference the object that the function is defined on.

I have a function defined as follows in `app/utils/report-error.js`:

```
reportError = function(err) {
  # ...
};
export default reportError;
```

And then I import that function elsewhere as follows:

```
import reportError from '../utils/report-error';
```

Is it possible to spy on this function using `sinon`? Normally I would refer to the object on which the function is defined:

```
sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
sandbox.spy(someObject, "reportError");
```

But what is the `someObject` of a bare function that gets imported?

I realize I could just put the function on an object and import the object, but that means that everywhere the function is used, I need to reference the receiver object too, which seems messy.

When the I look at the javascript that is produced after the `import` and `export` statements are transpiled, there is actually an object with a function on it:

```
reportError['default']();
```

But any mentions to `reportError` get similarly transpiled and there doesn't seem a way to refer to the host object of the dependency.

Thoughts?

Comment: any chance you found the answer to this?

Comment: One somewhat unsatisfactory hack is to put the actual implementation on an object, say called `hook` and have the exported default be a wrapper function that just calls `hook.reportError`. Then you can also export the hook so that it can be included in your tests. Then you stub on `hook` and any implementations that use the exported default, also call the version on `hook` which can be the version spied on. Make sense? Kind of ugly though.

Comment: ah I see, I was thinking of that too. Right now, stuck between leaving my 1 test that actually required sinon out and doing that which could lead other developers to think that they should/could be importing that whole file. Thanks